# R get all rows that have at least one number in each decade from 0 to 99

Tags: r

Having the following matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10]  [,11]  [,12] 
[1,]   23   14   17   10     2     6    90    45    56     25     11      9 
[2,]    1   15   18   21    32    46    55    50    61     73     81     93 
[3,]   56   19   98   23    42     7     8    25    61     54     22     38
```

I want to get only the rows that have at least 1 number in each of 10 decades from 1 to 99 
 So the result must be:

```
[1] False
[2] True
[3] False
```

Finally we get only [2] that satisfies the condition. Can you please provide an R language function which can generate this result?

Regards, 
Dimitris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
apply(m1, 1, function(x) length(unique(x %/%10))==10)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(23, 1, 6, 14, 15, 19, 17, 18, 98, 10, 21, 23, 2, 
32, 42, 6, 46, 7, 90, 35, 8, 45, 50, 25, 56, 61, 61, 25, 73, 
54, 11, 81, 22, 9, 93, 38), .Dim = c(3L, 12L))
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use the `setqual` function to check for set equality of the decades (0:9) with the contents of the row after using the integer division operator `%/%`.

```
apply(m1, 1, function(x) setequal(0:9, x %/%10))
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```